# How to set thumbnail for mp3 using eyed3 python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3, thumbnails, eyed3

I can't set image thumbnails for mp3 files using eyed3 module in Python.
I try next script:

```
import eyed3
from eyed3.id3.frames import ImageFrame

th = 'url_to_my_pic'
file = 'to_mp3_pleer/file.mp3'

audiofile = eyed3.load(file)
audiofile.initTag()
audiofile.tag.frames = ImageFrame(image_url=th)
audiofile.tag.save()
```

But this do nothing with thumbnails in my file.
In google no information about settings thumbnails using eyed3. How can I set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours learning of eyeD3, googling and experimenting with file cover, I think, I have a solution for you.

You need to follow these rules:

- use ID3v2.3 *(not v2.4 as by default in eyeD3)*;
- add right description for cover image (*word `cover`*);
- pass image as **binary**;

I'll give you an example of code, which works fine on my Windows 10 *(should works on other platforms as well)*:

```py
import eyed3
import urllib.request

audiofile = eyed3.load("D:\\tmp\\tmp_mp3\\track_example.mp3")

audiofile.initTag(version=(2, 3, 0))  # version is important
# Other data for demonstration purpose only (from docs)
audiofile.tag.artist = "Token Entry"
audiofile.tag.album = "Free For All Comp LP"
audiofile.tag.album_artist = "Various Artists"
audiofile.tag.title = "The Edge"

# Read image from local file (for demonstration and future readers)
with open("D:\\tmp\\tmp_covers\\cover_2021-03-13.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    imagedata = image_file.read()
audiofile.tag.images.set(3, imagedata, "image/jpeg", u"cover")
audiofile.tag.save()

# Get image from the Internet
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com/your-picture-here.jpg")
imagedata = response.read()
audiofile.tag.images.set(3, imagedata, "image/jpeg", u"cover")
audiofile.tag.save()
```

**Credits:** My code is based on several pages: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515738/using-eyed3-to-embed-album-art-from-url), [2](https://tuxpool.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-store-images-in-mp3-files-using.html), [3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eyed3.mp3.html#module-eyed3.mp3)

Comment: Thank you very mach. It is helpful, although i used a workaround via youtube-dl parameters.